# Get image pixels from multiple viewer nodes

Tags: scripting, node-editor, normals, id-mask, depth-map

For Blender **2.81** and **Cycles** render.

I want to access all of the following data passes from a Python script:

- `Z`
- `Normal`
- `Vector`
- `Object Index`

[image]

Therefore, I created three Viewer Nodes with different names. See the following image:

[image]

The viewer node on the top is getting both the `Z` and the `Normal` passes. The one in the middle is getting the `Vector`, and the one in the bottom the `IndexOB`.

Now my issue is that when I use the following code `pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels`, I can only access the data from the top Viewer Node (we only get the pixel data of the node that was selected from the user interface).

Is there a way that I can specify through the NameId of the Viewer Node which pixels data do I want to access?

I tried selecting and activating the different nodes through a script but apparently the data does not get automatically updated. The viewer node has to be manually clicked to make it visually active which then updates the images['Viewer Node'] data that we want to access. I found more info about this "known limitation" [here](https://developer.blender.org/T54314).

Comment: similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32640/two-viewer-nodes-switch-between-output-images

Comment: Can you try to use one *Viewer* with *Switch* nodes or connect sockets via python for every case?

Comment: Tried switch nodes and the issue is the same. To connect via python for every case I would need to render multiple times. I want to render only once.

Comment: How exactly would you want to post the data?

Comment: I am converting the data to `numpy` arrays

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the File Output nodes?

Comment: I don't want to write to disk. That would be a different question.

Comment: I believe that you could combine the images in a specific way and recover the originals at the cost of bit depth. You have 128 bits per pixel from the viewer node (32 bits * 4 channels). For Z(1 channel) + norm(3) + vec(3) + index(1), you would need 8 channels giving you 16 bits per channel (128/8 = 16). Not sure exactly how to carry it out though since the values are floating-point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that will do the job in some cases:

Instead of multiple Viewer nodes use a single Viewer node and a switch to change the image input that the Viewer gets. For Example:

Old system with multiple Viewer nodes:
[image]

New system with one Viewer node and a switch:
[image]

The switch can be toggled in python using the following command:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Switch"].check = False
```

If you need more than two rendering configurations (i.e. more than two Viewer nodes in the old system) you can use an array of Switch nodes:

[image]
Here is how to control the three Switch nodes in python, assuming you don't gives them custom names:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Switch"].check = False        # first Switch
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Switch.001"].check = False    # second Switch
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Switch.002"].check = False    # third Switch
```

Although this won't solve the problem in the original at the time of writing almost two years old question, I hope it will provide a solution to other people like me stumbling across this thread in search of answers.